# How can I make this code compile and run? How to convert to primitive recursion?

Tags: haskell

The following code is supposed to return the denotation of a Poly expression. For instance (\x -> x + x) would be the returned denotation for expression (PAdd PVar PVar). I have not written this code myself, so I am not sure how to run it.

```
data Poly = PConst Int |
            PVar |
            PAdd Poly Poly |
            PMul Poly Poly

compilePoly :: Poly -> (Int -> Int)
compilePoly (PConst x) = (\_ -> x)
compilePoly (PVar) = id
compilePoly (PAdd p1 p2) = (\x -> (compilePoly p1 x) + (compilePoly p2 x))
compilePoly (PMul p1 p2) = (\x -> (compilePoly p1 x) * (compilePoly p2 x))
```

I tried running it like this(and a couple other ways), but it never compiles.

```
main = do
print $ compilePoly $ PAdd PVar PVar
```

I also need to know how this can be converted to primitive recursion. I can think of no such way. The data type Poly has 4 cases and they all need to be addressed. Primitive recursion would require a 0-case and a non-zero case. I thought that maybe I can apply that to each case, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide it with an input.  value.  You have `compilePoly (PAdd PVar PVar) :: Int -> Int`, and this can't be printed.  Instead, try

```
main = print $ compilePoly (PAdd PVar PVar) 1
```

This will be equivalent to `(\x -> x + x) 1`, resulting in `2`.

---

What might make this more clear would be defining `compilePoly` a bit differently:

```
compilePoly :: Poly -> Int -> Int
compilePoly (PConst c)   x = c
compilePoly (PVar)       x = x
compilePoly (PAdd p1 p2) x = compilePoly p1 x + compilePoly p2 x
compilePoly (PMul p1 p2) x = compilePoly p1 x * compilePoly p2 x
```

Now it should be obvious that `compilePoly` actually takes 2 arguments, where the second is your variable's value.  All that I did here was move the `\x ->` to the left side of the `=` sign (and renamed `(PConst x)` to `(PConst c)`).  You can always make the following transformations

```
f = \x y -> <something x y>
f = \x -> \y -> <something x y>
f x = \y -> <something x y>
f x y = <something x y>
```

Where `<something x y>` is some expression using `x` and `y`.  All of the above lines are equivalent in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks very much. Very good explanation. Would have taken me a long time to figure out, because I am new to Haskell.

Comment: @RumenHristov You are already writing code quite well, luckily you had a simple problem to solve.  I've added some more to my answer to hopefully help explain what I did to move the `x` argument to the left hand side of the `=`.  I hope this helps your understanding of the problem.

Comment: How can I convert this code to primitive recursion? I updated the qustion a bit.

Comment: @RumenHristov I don't think it's possible to do primitive recursion with an ADT, at least not with some significantly more advanced techniques.

Comment: Isn't this definition already primitive recursive, due to having a non-recursive base case for PConst Int and recursive cases for PAdd Poly Poly and PMul Poly Poly?

Comment: @RumenHristov What's your definition of [primitive recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function)?  Using what Wikipedia says, I would say that what you have would be primitive recursion.

Comment: I think so too. My definition is having one base case in the definition of compilePoly, which goes directly to a value without calling itself. And the rest should be all recursive calls. I have that in compilePoly (PConst x) = (\_ -> x). This is non-recursive. The rest are all recursively defined. At least that's how I'm seeing it, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65086/discussion-between-bheklilr-and-rumen-hristov).

Answer (score 2):

`compilePoly` takes a `Poly` and returns a *function*. You can't print functions. You can execute them though:

```
main = do
  let f = compilePoly $ PAdd PVar PVar
  print (f 17)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the type signature for `compilePoly`, it's `Poly -> (Int -> Int)` - you need to pass an `Int` to get a result, like `compilePoly (PAdd PVar PVar) 0`